# Passing an array of arguments

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I'm trying to have a function that is passed a function and calls it with a set of args.  For example:

```
function foo(func, args) {
  return func(args);
}
```

However, I don't know how many elements might be in args, and func should be able to be an arbitrary function that takes any number of args.  How do I deal with this?

Also say I wanted to store the functions passed to foo and only call them if they hadn't been called before.

Can I just do something like:

```
var calledFuncs = [];
function foo(func, args) {
  if(calledFuncs.indexOf(func) === -1) {
    calledFuncs.push(func);
    return func(args);
  }
}
```

Thanks, I'm a bit new to functional programming in JavaScript.

Comment: If there will be a lot of `calledFuncs`, then another *(faster)* solution to prevent recalling would be to put a property directly on the function as a flag. Since functions are Objects, you can add properties just like any other object. Of course the property will be accessible to any code that can access the function, so keep that in mind.

Comment: If it's for understanding the language and not for compatibility, you can also use a `WeakMap` of function/called pairs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're looking for `func.apply`:

- the first argument is the context aka `this` value. You don't want to change this, so pass it through.
- the second argument is an array containing the arguments, which can of course be of dynamic length.

So you could do this:

```
return func.apply(this, args);
```

You seem to have a fine approach to your second issue (with the `func(args)` replaced). You may want to store the return value of called functions, though, since `foo` now returns `undefined` for any calls except the first.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply):

```
func.apply(this, args);
```

`apply` takes an array of arguments as the second argument.

The first argument to `apply` will be the value of `this` in the scope of the function that you are calling. So you can pass in the current `this` or anything else that you want.

<s>As far as your second question goes, that will only work for named functions. You can use `func.name` to store the function name in your array:</s>

```
var calledFuncs = [];
function foo(func, args) {
   if(calledFuncs.indexOf(func.name) === -1) {
      calledFuncs.push(func.name);
      return func(args);
   }
}
```

This won't work for anonymous functions and it doesn't work for named functions in IE or Opera. You're going to have to parse it out, perhaps like so:

```
var name = func.toString().replace(/\n/g, "").replace(/\s*\(.*$/, "").replace(/^\s*function\s+/, "");
```

As far as your second question goes, you can do what you're doing right now. But I don't think it would work for the following case:

```
foo(function() {
}, []);

foo(function() {
}, []);
```

It will call both of those functions.

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean with the named functions requirement. `indexOf` can search for functions, whereas distinct functions can have the same name.

Comment: It won't matter if the function is named or not. It'll be testing for unique object instances. Using `.name` would be dangerous, as two functions can have the same name.

Comment: @amnotiam How would you look up an anonymous function without a reference to it?

Comment: @VivinPaliath: They're all object references, so the `indexOf` is doing a reference comparison.

Comment: `var a = [function(){},function(){}]; a.indexOf(a[1]) === 1;`

Comment: Of course, because `a[1]` points to the same reference. How about this: `foo.call(function() {}, []);` and then `foo.call(function() {}, []);`. The two `function() {}` aren't the same are they?

Comment: @Vivin Paliath: Indeed not, so `indexOf` will work fine. What is the issue you're trying to find a solution to?

Comment: @VivinPaliath: I see what you mean. It depends on the intent of the OP's code. Two identically behaving functions can be two different function objects. We don't know if OP cares what the function does or not.

Comment: @pimvdb `indexOf` will work fine for named functions or if you have a reference to an anonymous function, but if he calls `foo` with a function literal, and then calls it again with an identical function literal, it will call the second literal as well.

Comment: @Vivin Paliath: Ah, well, depends on what's "identical". At least, the two functions don't `===` each other.

Comment: @pimvdb right. Though functionally-identical (pun not intended) they aren't when you compare references.

Comment: @VivinPaliath it's impossible to statically determine if two functions are functionally equivalent, more so with just looking at the `.name`. There is infinite amount of ways to write a functionally equivalent function of some other function. The only sensible thing to do is to compare references.

Comment: ...on the other hand, for the same (or opposite) reason, `.name` isn't safe, as two differently behaving functions can have the same name.

Comment: @Vivin Paliath: Be careful with that though; even identical source code does not mean identical functionality. In the end it depends on its variable scope etc.

Comment: @primvdb Yup, understood that part. I initially went with `name` because I didn't even consider that you could compare references with `indexOf` like that. I spend too much of my time in Java and so I forget that you can do that in Javascript's `indexOf`.

Answer (score 1):

You want [`Function.prototype.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply):

```
func.apply(this,args);
```

Set the context (the first argument) to whatever you want, including `null` to get the `window` global (as you would get with your current `func(...)` invocation.

*Although not directly related to your question, see also the related [`Function.prototype.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Call) method that allows you to similarly set the context, but pass explicit parameters.*